# Link not opening during web page automation with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, nosuchelementexception

I have been trying to automate a browser operation via selenium, the goal is - `google.com` will be opened, `gmail` text will be searched and the first link will be clicked and opened. The code used is --

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement searchbox= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
        searchbox.sendKeys("gmail");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a")).click();
}
```

but nothing is happening, I am getting an error -

> error-Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a"}

where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Xpath in your code is in wrong format:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a")).click();
```

Please use the following Xpath is will work perfectly.

```
  WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            WebElement searchbox= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
            searchbox.sendKeys("gmail");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/div[1]/div[1]/div/h3/a")).click();
```

Xpath what I modified is.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/div[1]/div[1]/div/h3/a")).click();
```

Comment: I'm sure xpath is the only problem here ..above ticket has a solution to this issue

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/div[1]/div[1]/div/h3/a")).click() 

this is correct xpath

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether you use `/` or `//`. Both return the same results. However for the sake of coding standards your xpath format is proper. But if you look at it in a different way using `//` should be more helpful if at all there are elements that are between those html elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you are trying to click the first link (gmail) even before its loaded. Update your code to implement a `wait` until the element loads after you search for something and click on the search button. There are many types of `wait` available in Selenium, use explicit waits to wait between two actions and **it's my most preferable method**. Here's how -

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a"))).click(); //explicitly wait for the element to load and then click
```

- [More about Explicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Another better way to handle this is to wait for the element to appear and keep polling the page if the element showed up using Fluent waits. Here's how -

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); //create a fluent wait object
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a"))).click(); //fluent wait until element loads
```

- [More about Fluent Waits](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

You can also use an implicit wait time. which waits for a predefined time after each and every action that selenium performs. But it's again a non preferable one as it can throw errors at times when performance of the webpage is slow. Here's how -

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //implicitly wait until element loads for predefined time
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

- [More about Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits)

However, the easiest one that solves your issue is to use a simple `sleep()` method, **which i don't prefer** is using the `sleep()` method. I don't prefer it is because it can throw errors at times when elements take longer time to load, because selenium waits for a predefined time that you specify, which is a bad standard of coding.  Here's how -

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000); //Use sleep() method to wait for a predefined time
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']//div[1]//div[1]//div//h3//a")).click();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i am seeing my dynamic id are been used, it not recommended to use dynamic ids[as it will be keep changing], also use necessary wait conditions to avoid such exceptions

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")); //lst-ib is dynamic value.
```

i tried to replicate your scenario, no issues observed, please find the coding below,

```
package testclasses;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class classa extends classparent {

    @Test
 public void methoda() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/"); 


      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Gmail')]")));

      WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Gmail')]"));


      if(close.isDisplayed()){
         System.out.println("element is visible " +close);
         close.click();
      }

      else{
          System.out.println("element is not visible " +close);
      }
      }
}
```

console output,

```
TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Mohan Raj S\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1635948262\testng-customsuite.xml

element is visible [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (6d5bc9d3-cdff-4831-991a-69d7d7ce3d36)] -> xpath: //a[contains(text(),'Gmail')]]
PASSED: methoda

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: `"lst-ib"` wasn't the issue that OP was facing and he hasn't asked about it above.